# Selecting in a n:m relationship table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and a n:m relationship table, like this:

```
tb_1
-----
id_1
1
2
3

tb_2
-----
id_2
10
11
12

tb_nm
-------
id_1   id_2
 1      10
 1      11
 2      10
 3      10
```

I want select only the id_1 that have in the tb_nm rows witg id_2 = 10 AND 20..
In other words... I that case, i want to return only the id_1 = 1, because is the only that have id_2 = 10 and 11.

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    id_1 
FROM
    tb_nm
WHERE
    id_2 = 10
    AND id_2 = 11
```

and it returned zero rows.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT 
    id_1 
FROM
    tb_nm
WHERE
    id_2 IN (10,11)
```

and it returned all the rows...
Any suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to approach these problems using aggregation and the `having` clause.  This is a very flexible way of expressing these conditions.

For your particular case:

```
select id_1
from tb_nm
group by id_1
having sum(id_2 = 10) > 0 and
       sum(id_2 = 11) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows in each group of `id_1` values where one of the conditions is true.

If you wanted to add another condition, it is quite easy.  For instance, if you want no `12`s in the result, that is just another having condition.  Count the number of rows with that value and check to be sure there are none:

```
having sum(id_2 = 10) > 0 and
       sum(id_2 = 11) > 0 and
       sum(id_2 = 12) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tt.id_1 
FROM tb_nm tt
WHERE tt.id_2 = 10
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tb_nm ex
    WHERE ex.id_1 = tt.id_1
    AND ex.id_2 = 11
    );
```